# Override text called with Character in Renpy game

Tags: python, renpy

I would like to change the text echoed using the Character class to use context.

Let's say my main character name is stored in a variable, every other Character use this variable to call him in dialogues, but i want this variable replaced is certain condition. I would like to check these condition in a meta context (don't want to change every dialogue texts, just catch some dialogue in a function to update text)

I searched into the Character class, and Character callbacks, even with the translation method, but i can't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well, but I'll add an example of what I understood and you'll tell me :

```
define hero = Character("[player_name]")
define sis = Character("Lola")
define mom = Character("Ariel")
define friend = Character("Elsa")

label start:
    hero "My name is :"
    $ player_name = ("What is your name ?")
    $ player_name = povname.strip()
    friend "Hey [player_name] !"
    sis "Hey bro !"
    mom "Hey son !"
```

Hope this looks like what you intend to get.
Now if you want to consider custom names, like "Brother" instead of "Bro" for example, you could just :

```
default from_sis = ""
default from_mom = ""

label custom_names:
    $ from_sis = ("How does your sister call you ?")
    $ from_sis = povname.strip()
    $ from_mom = ("Same for your mother")
    $ from_mom = povname.strip()
    sis "Hey [from_sis]"
    mom "Hey [from_mom]"
```

Remember that the Character class is only here for the renpy.say function, and the string variable you'll store as a name is just used for writing it in textblocks. Any other string variable can be used for anything. Hope this was your issue and that I fixed it, if not, I'll gladly help you again :)